# Why am I getting a "Variable not found" error in this Robot Framework code using DataDriver?

Tags: robotframework

I am attempting to use the DataDriver package https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-datadriver/ with Robot Framework to generate a test report from a csv file generated in a test run. Here's the contents of the file:

```
${testid},${crc},${rrc}
100,1,0
101,1,1
102,0,1
```

The robot file is:

```
| *** Settings ***   |
| Library            | DataDriver | file=cr-run.csv | encoding=utf-8
| Test Template      | Check Capture Replay Record

| *** Test Case ***
| Check Capture Replay Record ${testid}

| *** Keywords ***
| Check Capture Replay Record
| | [Arguments] | ${testid}
| | ...         | ${crc}
| | ...         | ${rrc}
| | Should Be Equal As Integers | ${crc} | ${rrc}
```

The error is `Variable '${testid}' not found.`

Datadriver works fine for other examples. I have tried many variations and read available docs, but I am stumped. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you only have one space between `Check Capture Replay Record` and  `${testid}`. Was that intentional?

Comment: Not exactly intentional, but after I changed it to two spaces, " | ", or  removed it entirely,  I still get '${testid}' not found.